# Calling useInfiniteQuery with tRPC results in a TRPCClientError due to cursor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, zod, trpc

I was previously calling the `useQuery` hook with tRPC in order to fetch data without issue. However, when I transitioned over to `useInfiniteQuery` a `TRPCClientError` occurred.

This has something to do with the `cursor` used to track pagination which was not passed into the initial call (as this is not required per the [docs](https://trpc.io/docs/reactjs/useinfinitequery)). It is instead declared in the procedure for the tRPC router.

Failed GET request with a 400 HTTP response code.

```
TRPCClientError: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "cursor"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by ensuring that the Zod type assertion for the `cursor` is `nullish`. For the first page that is requested it's value is `undefined` as initially there is nothing to track.

```
import { initTRPC } from '@trpc/server';

export const t = initTRPC.create();

export const appRouter = t.router({
  infinitePosts: t
    .procedure
    .input(z.object({
      someInput: z.string(),
      cursor: z.number().nullish(), // <-- cursor must be nullish
    }))
    .query(({ input }) => {
      const { someInput, cursor } = input;
      /* Some logic to query database... */
      return {
        dbResult,
        nextCursor,
      };
    })
})
```